# Timer triggering an alarm

Tags: plc

I am writing a program to open and close some doors with ladder logic. I am using x0, x1,x2,and x3 as inputs, y0,y1,y2,y3 as non latching outputs,y4 and y6 as latching. What I would like to do is when a pulse is recived by x0,x1, or x2 it should open door 1,2, or 3. After 10 mins of opening doors 1-3 then an alarm should go off. If doors 1,2,3 are open then door 4 can not be opened. Im having problems with getting the timer to successfully trigger the the alarm(y4) to turn on and turn off when doors 1-3 are triggered to close.

Comment: can you post some pics of the ladder logic?  Perhaps that would help me identify where you problem is.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Direct 6 is what I am using.